# WAMP Virtual host not working properly

Tags: php, apache, wamp, virtualhost, document-root

I've been configuring my virtual hosting, with the following code:

```
<Virtualhost *:80>

    ServerName devproject.local
    ServerAlias devproject.local

    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/devproject"
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/devproject">
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</Virtualhost>
```

And wanted the result, that whenever I connect to 'devproject.local/', the project 'devproject' (which is located in my root directory 'C:/wamp/www/devproject) actually loads in.

The effect i'm currently having, is that the whole root ('/www/' directory) is loading in. So the URL has to be 'devproject.local/devproject' instead of 'devproject.local' for loading in the project.

Could anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: did you modify your hosts file too?

Comment: @danleyb2 Yes, it is loading though. But not the correct directory. Instead of loading the project 'devproject', it is showing me the main root ('/www/') directory (the list where every single project is listed in).

Comment: Config looks good so I'd say this vhost is not being used for some reason and other config (perhaps the main config ) is what is being used instead.

Comment: @BazzaDP What'd you mean by that, the apache is letting me in though, so it must be working? I've also tried using VirtualDocumentRoot, but having the same effect..

Comment: Does your main config file point DocumentRoor to C:/wamp/www/ and did you include above vhost in a file which is not loaded at all? In that case the main config file would be used and you would see exactly the symptoms you are seeing.

Comment: Nevermind, the file itself wasn't loaded in. I'm stupid, thanks though!

Comment: Not too familiar with Windows Apache set up but normally you have a httpd.conf which is the main config file. It the can include other config file such as extra/httpd-vhosts.conf file but that is typically commented out by default. So if it is still commented out in httpd.conf then it doesn't matter what you add in your vhosts file as it will be ignored until you include that in your mail httpd.conf file and restart Apache.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in comments:

Apache typically has the main config in the conf/httpd.conf file.

Typically this contains a line such as this:

```
#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Due to that # at the beginning this extra config file is commented out and not included. Therefore any config in this vhosts file is not used.

You probably have the main DocumentRoot httpd.conf set to C:/wamp/www/ hence why Apache will return return the website at http://devproject.local/devproject despite not loading this vhost file.

Btw if you only have on host in the Apache instance then normally don't need vhosts file (hence why it's commented out by default). It's more useful when you have multiple hosts on the same site (under different DNS names or ports).